The Box-Jenkins methodology provides two principles to select among equivalent models.1. Parsimony,2. Invertibility
In Invertibility -When choosing parameters in MA processes
(either pure MA or ARMA), always select parameter values
so that the MA coefficients are invertible. Because any
MA(q) model has 2^q equivalent representations, requiring
invertibility is a simple method to choose one of these
representations.
I can't Understand The part of MA(q) has 2^q equivalent representations.What it means by 2^q eqivalent repesentations ?
it is maths,theory or what

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
